# Instantiate a modelForms MultiSelectCheckBox widget

Tags: django, django-forms

I am using `ModelForms` with a `ModelMultipleChoiceField` widget. I have 2 questions:

1. My checkbox widget for Treatment Options from `SelectOptionForStateForm` renders existing selections from the `stateoption` table in my database. How does it know to look in that table for existing records? In my views.py I am only passing the `disease` and `state` objects which do not look at the `stateoption` table.
2. How do I instantiate my `SelectOutcomeForOptionForm` so that my Treatment Outcomes checkbox is also pre-selected from the `stateoptionoutcome` table in my database?

forms.py

```
class SelectOptionForStateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model = State
       exclude = ['state', 'relevantdisease']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       disease=kwargs.pop('disease', None)
       super(SelectOptionForStateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.fields['relevantoption']=forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Option.objects.filter(relevantdisease_id=disease),required=True, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
       self.fields['relevantoption'].label="Treatment Options"

class SelectOutcomeForOptionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model = StateOption
       exclude = ['partstate', 'partoption']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       disease=kwargs.pop('disease', None)
       super(SelectOutcomeForOptionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.fields['relevantoutcome']=forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Outcome.objects.filter(relevantdisease_id=disease),required=True, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
       self.fields['relevantoutcome'].label="Treatment Outcomes"
```

views.py

```
def stateoptionoutcome(request, disease_id, state_id):

    state = get_object_or_404(State, pk=state_id)
    disease = get_object_or_404(Disease, pk=disease_id)

    if request.method == "POST":
        optionForm = SelectOptionForStateForm(request.POST, disease=disease, instance=state)
        outcomeForm = SelectOutcomeForOptionForm(request.POST, disease=disease, instance=state)

        if optionForm.is_valid() and outcomeForm.is_valid(): 
           #Deletes state objects so there are no duplicate options in the database
           try:
               state_option = StateOption.objects.filter(partstate=state).delete()

           except StateOption.DoesNotExist:
               state_option = None

           #Saves user options to database
           for option_id in request.POST.getlist('relevantoption'):
               state_option = StateOption.objects.create(partstate=state, partoption_id=int(option_id))

               #Deletes stateoption objects found in StateOptionOutcome 
               try:
                   state_option_outcome = StateOptionOutcome.objects.filter(stateoption=state_option).delete()

               except StateOptionOutcome.DoesNotExist:
                   state_option_outcome = None

               #Saves user outcomes to database
               for outcome_id in request.POST.getlist('relevantoutcome'):
                   state_option_outcome = StateOptionOutcome.objects.create(stateoption=state_option, relevantoutcome_id=int(outcome_id))

           return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('diseasestateoptionlist', kwargs={'disease_id':disease_id, 'state_id':state_id}))
```

models.py

```
class State(models.Model):
       state = models.CharField(max_length=255)
       relevantdisease = models.ForeignKey(Disease)
       relevantoption = models.ManyToManyField(Option, through='StateOption')

class StateOption(models.Model):
       partstate = models.ForeignKey(State)
       partoption = models.ForeignKey(Option)
       relevantoutcome = models.ManyToManyField(Outcome, through='StateOptionOutcome')

class StateOptionOutcome(models.Model):
       stateoption = models.ForeignKey(StateOption)
       relevantoutcome = models.ForeignKey(Outcome)
       outcomevalue = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve #2 using this:

```
stateoptionlist = StateOption.objects.filter(partstate_id=state_id) 
if not stateoptionlist:
    stateoption = state 
else: 
    stateoption = stateoptionlist[0]
```

I pass the `state` instance if the `stateoptionlist` returns an empty list (ie, there are no records in the `StateOption` table). Updating the views.py, for every `SelectOutcomeForOptionForm`, my instance is replaced with `stateoption`.

I'm interested to see if there's a more efficient way of solving #2.